# Sitecore Geo IP location region vs state

Tags: geo-location

I have been looking around most of the blog post, however there is no straight forward solution to get state details for any location.

Even Sitecore doc mentioned Geo IP location gives state but it fails to give any working example.
[Setting Sitecore Ip GeoLocation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation)

I'm bit confused here. Even this blogpost rule out what sitecore doc says.
[what is region code?](https://andrewwburns.com/2016/10/28/what-does-sitecores-geoip-return-for-region/)

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you look at the children of this item. It is how experience analytics turns the state abbreviation into a real word. /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Analytics Filters/Report Filters/State